# Multiple edit dropdownlist default selected value

Tags: angular, typescript, drop-down-menu

I have a "multiple edit" screen, where this is how I default the values on load:

```
private createFormGroupItem(item: ...): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      title: new FormControl(item.title, [Validators.required]),
      effectiveDate: new FormControl(item.effectiveDate, [Validators.required]),
      tariff: new FormControl(this.ddlTariff[0].tariffId, [Validators.required])
    });
  }
```

It works on the title and the date field (fills the saved values), but I am not sure what is the syntax to make the Tariff dropdown's saved value to be selected.

Basically the FormControl is filled with records, and I would like to have the one with the **item.tariff** value to be selected.

There is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s6ce9g?file=src/app/app.component.ts) that (partially) has this type of functionality, but I am not sure how to change that to actually test it with a real object on there like in my project.

Comment: I tested your stackblitz and for me all values are set `{Id: 0,ddlTariff: "5",exNo: 3,isDeRe: true,title: "sdfdsf"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private createFormGroupItem(item: ...): FormGroup {

let cucu = this.formBuilder.group({
  title: new FormControl(item.title, [Validators.required]),
  effectiveDate: new FormControl(item.effectiveDate, [Validators.required]),
  tariff: new FormControl(this.ddlTariff[0].tariffId, [Validators.required])
});

cucu.controls.Tariff.patchValue(item.tariff.tariffId);

return cucu;
}
```

this worked

Answer (score 0):

try this

init formgroup with default values:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
      title: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      effectiveDate: new FormControl(new date, [Validators.required]),
      tariff: new FormControl(0, [Validators.required])
    });
```

and then, assuming your item model matches the formgroup property names and types, do this

```
this.[formgroup].patchValue(item);
```

the patchvalue will put the values into the formgroup from your model,

not exactly sure your issue the id is in there,

[image]

Comment: This looks like the way to go, I am just not sure where actually should I put the patchvalue line. As you can see in my 5 lines of code, I have private createFormGroupItem and then I have return this.formBuilder.group. I am not very good with angular, and I am n ot sure where actually could I call the patchvalue from, being that there might be 10 records like this edited in the same time, all of them having different value to select

Comment: you seem to be doing allot of work that is not needed.  quite a messy design. you could have a listview on the left and just use selection changed event to pull data and have probably a table of some kind to display/edit the records

Comment: that is not something I can change though, this is system design